# Using Spring Security ACL with Spring Data REST

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest, spring-security-acl

I am trying to authorize apis exposed by Spring Data REST. So far I am able to do role-based authorization i.e:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(path = "book")
public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book, Long> {

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    <S extends Book> Book save(Book book);
}
```

Also in the same project i have a service layer with ACL mechanism, which is working.

I am unable to use PostFilter expression with Spring Data REST i.e:

```
@PostFilter("hasPermission(filterObject, 'read') or hasPermission(filterObject, admin)")
List<Book> findAll();
```

It would be of great help, if anyone using ACL with Spring Data REST.

Note: I am aware of below open issues:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/issues/619 (formerly DATAREST-236)

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/2629 (formerly SEC-2409)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

using JpaRepository was shadowing List<Book> findAll() method. Then I used CrudRepository, and PostFilter got applied.

For more details, a sample project is available on GitHub:
https://github.com/charybr/spring-data-rest-acl

ACL-based authorization is working for below entity exposed by Spring Data REST.

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;
import org.springframework.security.access.method.P;
import org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PostFilter;
import org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize;

@RepositoryRestResource(path = "book")
public interface BookRepository extends CrudRepository<Book, Long> {

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or hasPermission(#book, 'write')")
    <S extends Book> Book save(@P("book") Book book);

    @Override
    @PostFilter("hasPermission(filterObject, 'read') or hasPermission(filterObject, admin)")
    Iterable<Book> findAll();
}
```

Comment: You sir deserve an upvote (even a year and a half later) for taking the time to come and post the answer to your own problem. Thank you !

Comment: How to filter the results using `@PostAuthorize` within a `findAll()` function based on individual entity values inside the pageable array?

Comment: @W.M. for pageable `@PostAuthorize` is not a good idea. Please refer to https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#data-query